# Create files in a specific directory

Tags: python, file, path

I am trying to create a file (.txt) in the data directory but it creates a folder

This is the code I am using

How can I create the file

```
lenID = abs(len(id) - 5)
nameid = ""
for i in range(lenID):
    nameid += "0"
nameid += id
self.pathID = os.getcwd() + "\\Backup\\Data\\" + nameid
self.pathimages = os.getcwd() + "\\Backup\\Data\\" + nameid + "\\Contacts"
pathlogo = os.getcwd() + "\\Backup\\Data\\" + nameid + "\\Logo"
pathimeeting = os.getcwd() + "\\Backup\\Data\\" + nameid + "\\Meeting"
pathnote= os.getcwd() + "\\Backup\\Data\\" + nameid + "\\Notes.txt"
pathID = os.path.join(os.getcwd() + "\\Backup\\Data\\" + nameid)
####### CREATE FOLDER
if not os.path.exists(pathID):
    os.mkdir(pathID)
if not os.path.exists(self.pathimages):
    os.mkdir(self.pathimages)
if not os.path.exists(pathlogo):
    os.mkdir(pathlogo)
if not os.path.exists(pathimeeting):
    os.mkdir(pathimeeting)
if not os.path.exists(pathnote):
    os.mkdir(pathnote)
self.ui.label_2.setText(self.pathID)
self.Cargar(self.pathimages)
self.Logo(pathlogo)
self.Notes(self.pathID)
```

Comment: your question is unclear, also provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) creates a directory, wheras [`os.mknod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mknod) creates a new filesystem node (file), so you should change the applicable function calls to that.

Alternatively, (due to `os.mknod()` not being great cross-platform), you can `open` a file for writing then immediately close it again, thus creating a blank file:

```py
with open(pathnote, 'w'): pass
```

Comment: Consider using `pathlib.Path.touch` instead, which won't delete the file if it happens to exist beforehand.